# Azure Key Vault Secret Nos of Hits & Logging of same on Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

We are having common key vault azure component resource for our different Application Service which are being deployed on Azure App Service. Each App Service have separate Log Analytics is configured. Each App Service using specific Secrets Value only from Key Vault. But We found that all of Azure Key Vault Secret get url Hits are being logged on only one of App Service Log Analytics only. So due to that it is showing Nos of Key Vault secret usage is High for one app service only.

So we need help the reason behind this & somehow we can identify source url/application service which being accessing all secrets from Key Vault.

Comment: If all of the app service use 1 app service plan?

Comment: Yes we have 3 app service slots under 1 app service plan

Comment: Then you might be checking the app service plan logs. add some more criteria to the Loganalytcis query  for appservice specific.

Comment: We are checking with respective app service - application insights - logs only, still we are getting all hits logs viewed on single app service - app insight only.